# Callback to integrate an Anylogic model in a Java custom software

Tags: anylogic

I will write a model with Anylogic that has to be integrated with a Java software, that will read and write model values.
While coding, I read how to poll the Model values, create a new Simulation object, and access all the data inside.
I.e.:

```
final public Simulation anylogicSimulation = new Simulation();
mainAgent = (Main) anylogicSimulation.getEngine().getRoot();
mainAgent.anything_in_the_model;
```

I created a thread that polls the model any second and reads the value, and this concept works fine.
Since I can operate with any function and item in the whole project, is there any way to expose any callback function toward the external Java program to get model-updated values without polling them?
Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: make the function you need public?

Comment: Hi @Benjamin I already can read functions from the Model, accessing them in the way I wrote. But they're functions that have to be called. I wanted to create a public callback function to be associated with a listener and so be executed asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You can create callbacks on agents using "Action" parameters:
[image]

Add arguments as you would for functions. Then, call it in the model when needed to trigger the callback, for example:
[image]

Now, you can setup external programs to "listen" to the callback as needed.